# Data file read/write from within IBM Q-Experience Jupyter notebook

Tags: ibm-q-experience

In IBM Q-Experience how can I upload a data file that I intend to read from the python code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the Qiskit Notebooks section, you will see this button [image]

If you click import you can chose to upload the file from your computer into IQX.

Comment: Yes, but one can only upload ipynb files, not any other file, like a csv file.

Comment: I followed this method and I was able to upload a csv, you just cannot open them inside IQX. Are you receiving an error message when you try to?

Comment: no, but it does not show it. So if I upload a csv this way, I can access it from the code as if its is in the same directory as the code, is it?

Comment: amazing!!, it did work! Many many thanks met927!

Comment: I had to close and re-open my notebook for it to see an imported .py file, but then it worked. Thanks for pointing out that Import can be used for non-ipynb files!